# Ramification index example.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ramification, unramified-extension

I was studying ramification index and I found the following definition:

Let $E/K$ a finite field extension, $\mathfrak{d}$ a DVR of $K$ with maximal ideal $m$ and $\mathfrak{D}$ a DVR of $E$ with maximal ideal $M$ such that $\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{D}\cap K$ and $m=M\cap K$. If $v_\mathfrak{d}$ and $v_\mathfrak{D}$ are the valuation of $\mathfrak{d}$ and $\mathfrak{D}$ respectively then the ramification index is defined as $|v_\mathfrak{D}(E\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace):v_\mathfrak{d}(K\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace)|$.

Equvialently if $m=(t)$ and $M=(u)$, the ramification index is the positive integer $e$ such that $t=u^ev$, with $v$ a unit of $\mathfrak{D}$.

I understand the definition, but it seems something very hard to compute. The examples I have found on internet are some difficut ones using $p$-adic numbers. I would like if you can give me two elementary examples (avoiding $p$-adic numbers) one where there are no ramification (ramification index $=1$) and one with ramification (ramification index $>1$).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take $F=\mathbb{Q}((t))$, and consider the extensions $K/F$, where $K$ is $L((t))$ ($L$ number field), or $F[x]/(x^3-2t)$, or $F[x]/((1-6t)x^3+x^2-t^2x-t)$. But honestly, it’s pretty hard to think of a reason to learn about ramification index that doesn’t involve $p$-adic numbers somewhere down the line – you might as well start learning about them now.

Comment: @Mindlack Yeah I know, not that I dont want to learn $p$-adic number, but I need ramifications to prove a theroem and I want to know something about ramifications before. Maybe you can give some details on the calculations of one of your examples? That is where I get stucked.

Comment: Hint: what is a uniformizer of $L((t))$? Of $\mathbb{Q}((t))$?

Comment: @Mindlack In both cases $t$ is a uniformizer and so the ramification is trivial (index 1) right?

Comment: Yes, that’s precisely it. Now what’s a uniformizer of $F[x]/(x^3-2t)$, where $F=\mathbb{Q}((t))$?

Comment: @Mindlack, That is where I am stucked, I dont know how to compute it.